# Canceling the incoming request with a button

Tags: angular, ajax, typescript, request, devtools

When I switch to a menu, I get data from the API. While this data is still typing pendig in DevTools, I click the Filter button and search for another data. The data I'm looking for comes to my table. But when the pending data comes, the data I search for disappears.

Command line where I get the data

```
  protected loadData = (params) => {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: this.tableUrl,
        data: params.data,
        beforeSend: (request) => {
            request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`);
        }
    }).done((response) => {
        params.success(response);
    });
}
```

[image]

The requests I received above. The top request takes about 40 seconds. The bottom takes 1 second. It fetches data in 1 second. Since the other takes 40 seconds, other data is added on top of the data that comes in 1 second after 39 seconds. I need to cancel requests that say "referenceTumList?PageIndex=0&PageSize=10" while I am filtering.

Comment: which angular version is this?

Comment: If you are using Angular, I recommend using http Observable to make API calls. It would be quite easy to cancel requests when another request is in progress. You can use switchMap operator or custom logic to cancel the request.

Comment: Angular version is 7.1.0 @zainhassan

Comment: I'll look into the switchMap operator thank you. Observable is used in many APIs, but when I work now, it is not available. That's why I'm having trouble. @RiteshWaghela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel ajax call like this

```
xhrReq: any;

protected loadData = (params) => {

if(this.xhrReq){
    this.xhrReq.abort();
}

this.xhrReq = $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: this.tableUrl,
    data: params.data,
    beforeSend: (request) => {
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`);
    }
}).done((response) => {
    params.success(response);
});
}
```

if you want to cancel call on button click

```
onButtonClick(){
    if(this.xhrReq){
        this.xhrReq.abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I assign to the button to cancel requests after using this?

Comment: I have updated the code. It should work when ever you call loadData function